# Deprecated Feature Used / Attempt to read property "#" on null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to output different options upon clicking them.
Ideally, the image , name, and price should change according to the options i click.
Look below link.

[image: img1]

however, once I click the options the image is blank, name doesnt change, and price says 'NaN'

[image: img2]

I have also looked into apache error

[image: apache error]

This is the php file of the img1 and img2 above
There is Ajax script inside.

```
</head>

<body id="body">
<body style="background-color: beige;">

<?php session_start();
include '../../includes/dbh.localhost.php';
if(!$_SESSION['AUID']){
    echo "<script>alert('권한이 없습니다.');history.back();</script>";
    exit;
}


$pid  = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : '';

$query="SELECT * from 제품 where pid=".$pid;
$result = $conn->query($query) or die("query error => ".$conn->error);
$rs = $result->fetch_object();


$query2="SELECT * from 제품옵션 where cate='컬러' and pid=".$pid;
$result2 = $conn->query($query2) or die("query error => ".$conn->error);
while($rs2 = $result2->fetch_object()){
    $options1[]=$rs2;
}


$query2="SELECT * from 제품옵션 where cate='사이즈' and pid=".$pid;
$result2 = $conn->query($query2) or die("query error => ".$conn->error);
$options2= [];
while($rs2 = $result2->fetch_object()){
    $options2[]=$rs2;
}

?>
<style>
    .col{
        border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    }

    [type=radio] {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    [type=radio] + span {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked + span {
        outline: 3px solid indigo;
    }
</style>

<section class="signin-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <div class="block text-center" style="background-color:#FFFFF0;">
         <div class="signinlogo">
         <div class="logo text-center">
                <a href="../../index.php"><tspan x="70.94" y="325">Sutra Craft</tspan></a>
            </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="text-align:center;">
      <img id="pimg" src="<?php echo $rs->thumbnail;?>" style="max-width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3><?php echo $rs->name;?></h3>
        <div>
          가격 : <span id="price"><?php echo number_format($rs->price);?></span>원
        </div>
        <?php if($options1){?>
        <br>
        
        <br>
        <div>
        <?php 
        
        foreach($options1 as $op1){?>
                <input type="radio" name="poption1" id="poption1_<?php echo $op1->poid;?>" value="<?php echo $op1->poid;?>">
                    <span  onclick="jQuery('#poption1_<?php echo $op1->poid;?>').click();" style="content: url('<?php echo $op1->image_url;?>');height:100px;width:100px;"></span>
                </input>
            <?php }?>
           
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <?php 
           
            foreach($options2 as $op2){
                $option_name=$op2->option_name;
                if($op2->option_price)$option_name.="(+".number_format($op2->option_price).")";
                ?>
                <input type="radio" name="poption2" id="poption2_<?php echo $op2->poid;?>" value="<?php echo $op2->poid;?>">
                    <span  onclick="jQuery('#poption2_<?php echo $op2->poid;?>').click();"><?php echo $option_name;?></span>
                </input>
            <?php }?>
           
        </div>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>



<script>

    $("input[name='poption1']:radio,input[name='poption2']:radio").change(function () {
        var poid1 = $('input:radio[name="poption1"]:checked').val();
        var poid2 = $('input:radio[name="poption2"]:checked').val();
        
        
        var data = {
            poid1 : poid1,
            poid2 : poid2
        };
            $.ajax({
                async : false ,
                type : 'post' ,
                url : 'option_change.php' ,
                data  : data ,
                dataType : 'json' ,
                error : function() {} ,
                success : function(data) {
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    var price=parseInt(data.option_price1)+parseInt(data.option_price2)+<?php echo $rs->price;?>;
                    $("#pimg").attr("src", data.image_url);
                    $("#price").text(number_format(price));
                }
        });
    });

    function number_format(num){
        return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',');
    }

    $("#poption").change(function(){
        var poid = $("#poption option:selected").val();
       
        var data = {
            poid : poid
        };
            $.ajax({
                async : false ,
                type : 'post' ,
                url : 'option_change.php' ,
                data  : data ,
                dataType : 'json' ,
                error : function() {} ,
                success : function(data) {
                    var price=parseInt(data.option_price)+<?php echo $rs->price;?>;
                    $("#pimg").attr("src", data.image_url);
                    $("#price").text(number_format(price));
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is option_change.php for AJAX

```
<?php session_start();
include '../../includes/dbh.localhost.php';
ini_set( 'display_errors', '0' );

$poid  = isset($_POST['poid']) ? $_POST['poid'] : '';

$query="SELECT * from 제품옵션 where poid='".$poid."'";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die("query error => ".$conn->error);
$rs = $result->fetch_object();
$image_url = $rs->image_url;
$option_price = $rs->option_price;

$data = array("image_url"=>$image_url,"option_price"=>$option_price);
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

I know its a lot of codes, but If you can please help.

------------------------------after edit --------------------------------

Comment: Your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injections, take a look at [preparing queries](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Comment: Could you demonstrate the prepared statements on my php code?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: The error seems to point to `$rs` being null, so it can't read those properties from it. Therefore it must mean that your query did not return any rows. You need to debug that - check the $poid value, check the content of the database, check the SQL which was actually executed.

Comment: You are sending `var data = {
            poid1 : poid1,
            poid2 : poid2
        };
` to the server in the AJAX request. This will result in `$_POST["poid1"]` and `$_POST["poid2"]` existing, but your PHP code tries to find `$_POST["poid"]`, which does not exist. Really your code should have logged a warning about that too, I expect. I think this is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: P.S. You also specified another AJAX request inside `$("#poption").change(function(){` which sends `var data = {
            poid : poid
        };`... **but** this code will never be executed because there is no element with `id="poption"` in your HTML, therefore `$("#poption").change` will never be triggered.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for you insightful assessment. after reading what you have left here, I looked into my codes and understood the problem. Now no more console errors. However, the image still doesnt change nor the name nor price. I'm really confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code (vulnerability, formatting, etc.). But I will point you only to the direction I think you're interested in:

First: `$("#poption").change` never gets triggered, because there is no input with the id "***poption***". You should delete that.

Second:  `$("input[name='poption1']:radio,input[name='poption2']:radio").change` may get triggered but your ajax code posts *poid1* and *poid2* and not the *poid* that your option_change.php is expecting.
I don't know why you put the different names to the input. You should put the same name, like that:

> input type="radio" name="**poption**" id="poption1_poid;?>" value="poid;?>"

and

> input type="radio" name="**poption**" id="poption2_poid;?>" value="poid;?>">

Then modify the JQuery on change event according to that name: `input[name='poption']:radio`. Inside the event, store the value inside your data object like that:

```
var poid = $('input:radio[name="poption"]:checked').val();

var data = {
            poid : poid
        };
```

Comment: Thanks Leonard. Because of you i no longer get any console errors. However, even after fixing the issue, the image doesn't change (the main image is supposed to switch with the option image url i click) same for the name and price.

Comment: @JinSingh You should console log the returned data object from your ajax call and verify that it returns what you're expecting.